# How to rewrite txt file-why my code doesn't work

Tags: c#, file, url-rewriting, temp

I want rewrite my txt file(I need delete lines). I use this code:

```
 string cesta3 = cesta + "database.txt";
 string file = new StreamReader(cesta3).ReadToEnd();

 var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines(cesta3)
    .Where(l => l != "Meno: " + textBox1.Text + " PN " + textBox2.Text);
```

But I don't know how to save my file with that same name.I try this:

```
 File.WriteAllLines(cesta3, linesToKeep); // <== exception

 var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
 File.Move(tempFile + ".txt", cesta3);
```

But it throws exception:

> Additional information: Access to the path "'C:\Users\Lenovo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\attendancer\attendancer\bin\Debug\database.txt‌​' is denied."

How can I do ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is an exception being thrown or isn't anything happening?

Comment: Sorry this is exception :Additional information: Access to the path "'C:\Users\Lenovo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\attendancer\attendancer\bin\Debug\database.txt' is denied."

Comment: It seems as though this exception has nothing to do with the temp file. Could you mark the line in which the exception occurrs or try it without moving the file to the temp folder? Furthermore you could try deleting the file manually once and run the program again to be sure that the program has written it by itself.

Comment: Exception is in this line : "File.WriteAllLines(cesta3, linesToKeep);"

Comment: Side note: please make sure to [edit] information into the post rather than adding comments. Otherwise someone else will have to do that instead potentially marking wrong lines or changing question in way you don't intend to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code locks the file and prevent it from moving: `string file = new StreamReader(cesta3).ReadToEnd();`.

Fix:

- you can properly close `StreamReader` after reading `file` text from it with `using`
- alternatively since there is nothing in the sample using that `StreamReader` or result of `ReadToEnd` (`file` variable) you can simply remove that line.

Side note: `File.Move` will throw more exceptions after you are done with the first one as source file is unlikely to exist - I'm not sure what you were trying to do with that call.